# Android : Post data to a website via app and view results in app

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an application which converts a website to mobile format. There is a spinner in the app. So my doubt is, how do i pass these selected values from my spinner to the website to get  results?

Comment: I can get the results using Document object, i need a head start as how to pass the value to the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a http post request.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html.

NOTE : **If you are making network related operation you should use a AsyncTask other wise  you will get a NetworkOnMainThreadException (Honeycomb and later).**

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Some links with source code available in the links below

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/example-of-httppost-on-android.html

Comment: But I strongly advice to put the method body inside a AsyncTask and deliver the response to the caller via delegate or LocalBroadcastManager messages.

Comment: @Raghunandan, So for sending the data to a website i do need to see to which key i need to send the data right?and this is how you send the data in android. So if i am developing an app for some other website , i need to have the php file to proceed? Please correct me if i am wrong here.Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more clear. All you need is the url of the site and the content.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running the a mobile web application inside a WebView container you can use a well known library like jQuery an its ajax stuff.

Comment: , is not using a web container , i am able to pull the values from the website.But i need a head start as how to send some data to a website.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, it will help a lot to give better answers.